# React-Router having its own copy of React When Using Browserfy

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, react-router

I am using react-router alongside react and bundling them using browserify and gulp. Here is a snippet of my gulpfile.

```html
gulp.task('js', function () {
    var modularizedLibraries =
        [
            { file: 'react', expose: 'react' },
            { file: 'react-router', expose: 'react-router' },
            { file: 'jquery', expose: 'jquery' },
            { file: 'bootstrap', expose: 'bootstrap' }
        ];

    modularizedLibraries.map(function (file) {
        return browserfy(file)
                .require(file.file, { expose: file.expose })
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source(file.file))
                .pipe(rename({ dirname: '', extname: '.js' }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dest.js + "/libs"));
    });
```

When it outputs the file to my destination folder, react-router contains it's own copy of react code. So including both react and react-router.js produces numerous warnings and error.

Is there a way to disable including of react code inside react-router? Thank you.

Comment: What versions of each are you using & are you using npm or bower?

Comment: I am using the latest version of browserfy 11.0.1 and react/react-router 0.13.3. I use npm. If I specify the bundleExternal flag as false then it does not include react code inside react-router, but It now complains that it's missing some dependency such as Object.assign.

Comment: are you using reactify? if you are, try https://github.com/babel/babelify instead.